# Is the inverse function continuous at a fixed point?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity

Show that $f:I=(-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R},$
 it follows that $$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
 \quad1-x & \text{ as } -1<x\leq 0,  \\ 
 \frac{{x}^{-1}+ \lfloor {x}^{-1}\rfloor}{1+{x}^{-1}+\lfloor {x}^{-1}\rfloor}& \text{  as    }     \quad0<x<1 ,
\end{cases}$$ 
and $\lfloor x\rfloor=$max{$n\in\mathbb{Z}$|$n\leq x$}.

We can proof the mapping $f:(-1,1) \rightarrow f(I)$is bijective,so let $f^{-1}$ is the inverse function of $f$ .

- $f(x)$ is continuous at point  $x=0,$ whether $f^{-1}(y)$ is continuous at point $y=1=f(0)$ ?

---

In my way of thinking ,$f(x)$ is  continuous at point  $x=0$ and strictly monotonic on $(0-\delta,0+\delta)$,so  $f^{-1}(y)$ is continuous at point $y=1$ .but my textbook said that $f^{-1}(y)$ is discontinuous at point $y=1$ .The textbook only gave this conclusion,having no reason to supprot it  !
I want use Mathematica to get the graph of inverse function $f^{-1}(y)$,who can help me ? If I construct the graph of $f^{-1}(y)$,this question will be easily solved.

Comment: The function $f$ is not surjective as a map $I \to \mathbb{R}$, so $f(I)$ is 'missing' many intervals. For example, there is no $\delta>0$ such that $f^{-1}$ is defined on $(1-\delta, 1+\delta)$.

Comment: Anyone knows how to prove that the inverse is discontinuous at $y=1$?